# What does "Add foreign key properties to the ENTITY Entity" do?

Tags: entity-framework

What does checking the "Add foreign key properties to the ENTITY Entity" checkbox on the Add Association dialog do?

Does it just change the Model or does checking this box when creating an association modify the database in any way to add the foreign keys?

<sub>I tried looking this up on MSDN - [How to: Create and Modify Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.edm.common.associations%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true) which contains the useful link "For more information, see [Defining and Managing Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295848%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)" which as you can see gives the amazingly useful response of "This Topic Is No Longer Available".</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It adds foreign key properties to the entities allowing you to work with entity relationships at the database level in addition to the conceptual model level.

Comment: I think an example would help. Given classes `Customer` and `Order`, where `Order` has a `Customer` navigation property, the foreign key property that would be added might be `CustomerId`.